# HTML to ODT conversion

Tags: django

I want to convert my Django views to ODT and export them.
Is there any library that I can use?

I am already converting to PDF with pisa - want to add ODT as a supported format.

Thanks
Hari

Answer (score 1):

1. Python has [ODT writer in docutils library](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/odt.html)
2. You can directly manipulate XML inside ODT (it's a zipfile)
3. I googled [OOoPy](http://ooopy.sourceforge.net/) seems interesting

Comment: thanks for the links - I am kind of new to Django and Python - will play around with these and see how it goes.